# Method undefined even though I loaded the js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I loaded an external js and called one of the functions, but it says that "daterangepicker is undefined." Any ideas why? I'm sure it's in there.

Portion of the code....

```
$.getScript("../DateRangePicker/daterangepicker.js", function () {
    $('input[name="ctl00$PageContent$mydaterange"]').daterangepicker({
            "linkedCalendars": false,
            "locale": {
                "format": "MM/DD/YY",
                "separator": " - ",
                "applyLabel": "Apply",
                "cancelLabel": "Cancel",
                "fromLabel": "From",
                "toLabel": "To",
                "customRangeLabel": "Custom",
                "daysOfWeek": [
                    "Su",
                    "Mo",
```

Error is: JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'daterangepicker'

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a matter of scope within your external file.
Try creating the function this way:

```
Datetimepicker = function () { ... }
```

instead of :

```
Datetimepicker() { ... }
```

Comment: Can you post what you mean based on my sample code? Thanks @GertjanBrouwer

Comment: No, you have a function "Datetimepicker" in your external file, Change how you declare(create) that function so that it becomes a global function(can be used from anywhere).

Comment: Thanks @GertjanBrouwer .... This code worked fine before. I just moved it from the aspx page to an external js file. Hmmmm

Comment: Have you changed the function declaratin in datetimepicker.js? Or have you maybe copied the function and pasted it? Because that might be a problem. PS: paste the first 3 lines of your external datetimepicker.js here

Comment: Thanks. Here's the whole file.... cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js

Comment: I mean the contents of the file itself.